# How to install Epson L210 scanner in Ububtu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, upgrade, 16.04, scanner

Epson L210 printer and scanner was working in Ubuntu 14.04 but upgrading to 16.04 only printer is working. I have the scanner driver deb amd 64 package but I don't know how to install.

Comment: Hi apparently the deb package installs the sane drivers in the wrong directory for ubuntu 16.04, check out this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/791556/not-working-brother-scanner-in-ubuntu-16-04-though-driver-installed

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is a deb? The epson file (iscan) is not actually a deb even though it has ".deb" in the file name (eg iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb.tar.gz).

Is iscan installed? If not, try these directions:

1. Download the most recent [iscan software](http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.html).
2. Extract the software using archive manager (eg In Nautilus, right-click downloaded file and then Open With Archive manager)
3. Open a terminal and go to the extracted folder (eg In Nautilus, right-click extracted folder and then 'Open in Terminal').
4. Type `./install.sh`

For more info and in case of problems, see the [Epson installation guide](http://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/iscan_e.html#sec6-1):

Comment: I have followed the instructions -  but scanner is still not working. A message showing "could not send command to scanner check the scanner status"

Comment: @SamirBrahmachari Sorry for the slow response. This topic has been closed as a duplicate.  Is it a duplicate and do the links solve your problem? If not, please update your original question to show that it is not a duplicate.